# Unable to receive email from simple ajax php contact

Tags: php, contacts, contact-form

Hi I'm trying develop a simple contact form in php. I have done a lot of research but can't seem to solve this.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="contact-box-hide">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required placeholder="First Name">
                            <span class="first-name-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" required placeholder="Last Name">
                            <span class="last-name-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"  id="contact_email" name="contact_email" required placeholder="Email Address">
                            <span class="contact-email-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="subject" name="contact_subject" required placeholder="Subject">
                            <span class="contact-subject-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            <span class="contact-message-error"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <button id="contact-submit" class="btn custom-btn col-xs-12" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></button>
                            <span id="contact-loading" class="btn custom-btn col-xs-12"> <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.contact-box-hide -->
                    <div class="contact-message"></div>

                </form><!-- /#contact-form -->
```

And this is the PHP portion:

```
<?php
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $contact_subject = $_POST['contact_subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = "New Message from Website Form";
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    if($submit){

        //Prepare Email
        $from = 'From: My Website'."\r\n"; 
        $to = 'odeleon@outlook.com'; 
        $subject = "Message from United Passions for Christ.org";
        $body = "".
            "From: ".$first_name."\n".
            "E-mail: ".$contact_email."\n".
            "Message: ".$message."\n";

        //Send email
        if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        }

    }

    ?>
```

he contact form shows up OK and there aren't any php errors when the user hits submit. However the email never appears in my inbox. Any ideas?

Is there something that I'm missing from this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 //your code to submit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check **php.ini** file configuration, you can find that in **/etc/** directory.
Refer this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm